# how to assign keyboard shortcut for the typescript code window?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

in VS2012 (with the ts extension installed) it seems that typescript files (.ts) isn't recognized as a code window

meaning, if you are focused on another window, hitting F7 doesn't switch to the typescript window for focus.

Does anyone know a custom keyboard shortcut override I can create to allow me to switch to the .ts file?

thank you.

Comment: +1 It doesn't seem to do this for JavaScript or CSS either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of to navigate back to the code files for TypeScript, JavaScript, CSS and other files that aren't classed as "View Code" is this:

Use `CTRL` + `Tab` - this opens up an open file list. From here you can select the file to show.

This is actually a handy shortcut if you want to do the same as "View Code", but not go straight to the current "on top" code file - so it is worth knowing - even though it isn't going to be as fluid as your F7 shortcut.

If you want to use it like F7, just hit `CTRL` + `Tab` and then let go - the "on top" file will be selected by default.